# How to understand the order of decorator staticmethod and cache?

Tags: python, caching

I was solving the problem from leetcode using recursion,
since I want to use wrapper `cache` but the function is a class method, I decided to transform the function to a static method

```
from functools import cache
class Solution:
    @cache
    @staticmethod
    def f(n):
        return 0

s = Solution()
s.f(1)
```

However this gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.f(1)
TypeError: Solution.f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

On the other hand, if wrap it with `@cache` first, it works.

```
from functools import cache
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    @cache
    def f(n):
        return 0

s = Solution()
s.f(1)
```

From my understanding, wrapper's order is bottom to top, I think it make sense to first wrap the method to a staticmethod (thus not requiring "self"), then wrap it with cache, but the result shows otherwise, how to explain this behavior?

Comment: You don't call static methods on an instance, you call them on the class. It should be `Solution.tribonacci(param_1)`

Comment: @Barmar you *can* call them either way, that is a feature of the `staticmethod` descriptor